# Impute Pandas dataframe column with value from another row based on ID column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
id   name 
0    toto                    
1    tata
0    NaN
```

I would like to impute the name column missing value on the third row based on the id.
The desired dataframe would be:

```
id   name 
0    toto                    
1    tata
0    toto
```

I did the following:

```
df.loc[df.name.isna(), "name"] = df["id"].map(df["name"])
```

but it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? You have to be more explicit than that... what error do you get? You chose a bad example because your code works in that case. Does your real DataFrame contain names for the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,0],
              'name':['toto','tata',pd.NA]})

df = df[['id']].merge(df[pd.notna(df['name'])].drop_duplicates(),
                      how = 'left', 
                      on = 'id')
df
```

Comment: This actually only works if there are NaN values. if not, it generates more lines

Comment: try it with df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1,0],
              'name':['toto','tata','toto']})

Comment: Add .drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one value exists in the group, you can try

```py
df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())
```

```
print(df)

   name
0  toto
1  tata
2  toto
```

Or sort `NaN` to the last

```py
df = (df.sort_values('name')
      .groupby('id').ffill()
      .sort_index())
```